# Concurrent SortedList or O(log n) concurrent collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I need to cache a lot of data from database in ASP.NET MVC application and would like to use SortedList. I know .NET 4.0 added concurrent collections but there is no sorted collection. 
I was thinking to use SynchronizedCollection, but it is intensively using locks even for reads (if I am not mistaken), so I am looking for other options. Basically I need a concurrent collection with O(log n) access complexity.

**EDIT - Code based on Greg's answer**

```
void WrappedAdd(TKey k, TValue v)
{
  var copy = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>(_sortedList);
  copy.Add(k, v);
  _sortedList = copy;
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman I need the collection to be sorted. And as it will be pretty big I would like to avoid OrderByDesc calls...

Comment: Would you be returning the entire collection?  A single item does not need to sort.  A LINQ Where is going to be O(n).

Comment: @Blam Actually I will be using it as collection(like get most recent records) and also for single item fetching. That's why I need it to be sorted. Having it sorted will allow me to use binary search and at the same time it will be a collection/list...

Comment: By the way, how many readers and writers do you expect?

Comment: @GregRos On pick time ~400 reads and ~10 writes per second.

Comment: No, this is not the same. The point of immutable collections is that they use structural sharing. It means that operations on them don't return entirely new collections, but instead new versions share most of their structure with old versions, so very little reallocation is required. `SortedList` doesn't work this way. What you're doing there is copying every element in the collection, one by one. This is an `O(n)` operation that is prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements are pretty vague, so I don't really know what you want. Is the collection supposed to have indexing? Key-value semantics?

I'm not sure if this fits with what you want, but you could use the new Microsoft [immutable collections library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's currently available on NuGet as a preview. It contains sorted collections (sorted sets and dictionaries), among other things.

These collections aren't concurrent themselves (in fact, concurrency is a non-issue; they can't be modified). However, you can use them in a concurrent setting by wrapping them, and using a lock during a write. Reading is thread-safe because the only mutation is assigning a reference, which is an atomic operation, so you're guaranteed to get the most up to date results you possibly could.

They're tree-based so most operations are `log n`.

```
public class ConcurrentWrapper<TKey, T> {
    ImmutableSortedDictionary<TKey, T> _inner;

    public void Add(TKey key, T item) {
        lock (_inner) {
            _inner = _inner.Add(key, item);
        }
    }

    public T Get(TKey key) {
        return _inner[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. This is pretty close to what I am looking for. There's just one potential issue I see ... Wouldn't this cause problems for big collections. Since for each add it will return a new collection for big collections containing millions of records this can eat all memory.

Comment: The collections use structural sharing, which basically means that you're getting your old collection back, with just a few small changes (generally, not more than `log n`, and possibly less). This shouldn't cause memory problems, unless you're already almost hitting your memory ceiling. You can expect a lot more garbage collection, though.

Comment: Actually this can work then even with SortedList...Reads are thread safe anyway...The only thing I will need to do is something like the code in the question I have updated above.

Comment: Seems this is the way to go for me ... Just one more thing is there any resource I can see what data structures are these new classes use internally... I am thinking since I will need list functionality as well may be it would be better to go with ImmutableSortedSet..In this access will not be as efficient as for ImmutableSortedDictionary, but values list population will be faster... I just need to confirm

Comment: The sets and dictionaries are based on immutable AVL trees (including the hash-based ones; they just sort based on the hash). I think they're all based on the same implementation, so there shouldn't be many performance differences.
I really don't know why the dictionary doesn't support indexing the keys by sort order as well as key-based lookups. The data structure supports the capability in `O(log n)`. Maybe it's a design choice.

Comment: I went with ImmutableLit and a small note in your code you will need SyncRoot object instead of locking the collection instance. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. You don't need `SyncRoot` though. You're not actually performing operations on the collection itself. You can't. It's immutable.